# Limit showing array object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In the following code trying to implement limit number of result . First fetch all data from database using mongoose query. Then it will filter data based user search. That is result. I want to limit data in "result" array. Not "vidoes" array.

```
exports.getVideos = async (req, res) => {
  const word = req.query.keyword ? req.query.keyword : "";
  const limitCount = req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 2

  //fetching all data from database
  try {
    const videos = await Video.find()

  //filtering data from based user search
    const result = videos.filter(v =>
      ["title", "description"].some(prop =>
        v[prop].toLowerCase().includes(word.toLocaleLowerCase())
      )
    )
  //limit the result

    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send as below.

```
res.send(result.slice(0,limitCount));
```